# How to click on "Create Issue" button in Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

Hi i'm trying to get the "Create an Issue" button to click after filling out a form online. The form fills correctly I just need it to do the final piece and click on the "Create Issue".

Here's my setup and code
Microsoft Excel 2016 32bit

VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Waiting()
       Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))
End Sub

Sub IE_Wait(IE As InternetExplorer)
    With IE
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
            Call Waiting
           ' SendKeys "{ENTER}"
        Wend
        While .Document.ReadyState <> "complete"
            DoEvents
           Call Waiting
            'SendKeys "{ENTER}"
        Wend
    End With
End Sub

Sub FindAndTerminate(ByVal strProcName As String)
    Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess
    Dim strComputer, strList
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '" & strProcName & "'")
    If colProcess.Count > 0 Then
        For Each objProcess In colProcess
        On Error Resume Next
            objProcess.Terminate
        Next objProcess
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub make_tickets_with_me()
  Dim IE As InternetExplorer
  Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
  Dim x, Site, ASIN_1, ASIN_2, ASIN_3, ASIN_4, ASIN_5 As String
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim e
  Dim y, lLastRow As Long

  ' Kill any currently running Explorer Windows
  FindAndTerminate "iexplore.exe"

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

  With ThisWorkbook
    lLastRow = Worksheets("ASINs").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Count total Asins
    x = 2
    For x = 2 To lLastRow
    Debug.Print x
      ASIN_1 = Worksheets("ASINs").Range("A" & x).Value
      ASIN_2 = Worksheets("ASINs").Range("A" & x + 1).Value
      ASIN_3 = Worksheets("ASINs").Range("A" & x + 2).Value
      ASIN_4 = Worksheets("ASINs").Range("A" & x + 3).Value
      ASIN_5 = Worksheets("ASINs").Range("A" & x + 4).Value

      Site = "https://sim.amazon.com/issues/create?assignedFolder=5aec25c2-1135-4d36-b751-37d967c0a83e&title=Zappos+Unsellable+Test&description=Below+is+a+list+of+5+asins+that+are+unsellable%3A%20%0D%0A%0D%0A" + ASIN_1 + "%0D%0A" + ASIN_2 + "%0D%0A" + ASIN_3 + "%0D%0A" + ASIN_4 + "%0D%0A" + ASIN_5 + "%0D%0A%0D%0A&descriptionContentType=text%2Fplain&extensions%5Btt%5D%5Bimpact%5D=4&extensions%5Btt%5D%5Bcategory%5D=&authorizations%5B%5D=BREAK&authZCompression=v1"
      x = x + 4
'      Debug.Print ASIN_1 & ASIN_2 & ASIN_3 & ASIN_4 & ASIN_5
'      Debug.Print x
'      Debug.Print Site
''' BEGIN INTERACTION WITH IE
      Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

      With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Left = 25
        .Top = 25
        .Height = 700
        .Width = 1300
        AppActivate ("Internet Explorer")
        .Navigate Site
        IE_Wait IE
        Call Waiting
        IE_Wait IE
        Call Waiting
        Set e = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("span")
        ->>>>>>>If e.innerText = "Create an issue In Zappos Unsellable: Tickets" Then
        e.parentElement.Click
        Exit For
        End If

        'Set e = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("create")(0)
        'e.Click
'        SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}"
        Call Waiting
       .Quit
      End With
    Next 'Loop for x=2 to lLastRow, Adds 4 to x, then Next adds 1 to total of 5 per iteration
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Buttons").Activate
    MsgBox ("Tickets Created :)")
  End With


End Sub
```

I've added an arrow to where the error is.

Here's the Inspect for the button I want to click

```html
    </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <script type="jsv/50_"></script></div></section>

      <section class="wizard-step " id="wizard-step-2" data-wizard-step="2"><div data-module-name="App.Views.CreateWizardStep" data-template="#create-wizard-step-template"><script type="jsv#112_"></script>
      <div class="form-actions">
        <div class="view-state-initialized-visible" data-view="create">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit" data-csm-counter="createViewCreateButton">
            <span style="display: inline;" data-link="visible{:!~isUndefined(issue.assignedFolder)}"><span id="view-tag-157" data-module-name="App.Views.FolderDisplayView" data-template="undefined"><script type="jsv#170_"></script><span style="display: inline;" data-name="folder-label-completed-text" data-link="visible{:state == 'completed'}">
        <script type="jsv#219^"></script><script type="jsv#308_"></script>
        <script type="jsv#388^"></script>Zappos Unsellable: Tickets
              Create an issue in
              <script type="jsv/388^"></script>
        <script type="jsv/308_"></script><script type="jsv/219^"></script>
      </span><span style="display: none;" data-link="visible{:state == 'loading'}">
        <script type="jsv#172_"></script><i class="icon-spinner"></i><script type="jsv/172_"></script>
        Loading folder...
      </span><span style="display: none;" data-link="visible{:state == 'errored'}">
        Could not find folder
      </span><span style="display: none;" data-link="visible{:state == 'empty'}">
        Folder not specified
      </span><script type="jsv/170_"></script></span>
            </span>
            <span style="display: none;" data-link="visible{:~isUndefined(issue.assignedFolder)}">
              Create an issue
            </span>
          </button>
          <div class="alert alert-error pull-right" style="display: none;" data-link="visible{:!state.isValid}">
            Please correct the errors above
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="view-state-loading-visible alert alert-info" data-view="create">
          <script type="jsv#113_"></script><i class="icon-spinner"></i><script type="jsv/113_"></script>
          Creating your issue...
        </div>
        <div class="view-state-errored-visible alert alert-error" data-view="create">
          <strong>There was an error creating your issue:</strong>
          <div data-link="html{>state.createError}"></div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" data-csm-counter="createViewTryAgainButton">
            Try again
          </button>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="view-state-redirecting-visible alert alert-success" data-view="create">
          Redirecting you to
          <a href="/issues/undefined" data-link="href{:'/issues/' + issue.id}   data-issue-id{htmlAttr:issue.id}" data-issue-id="">
            your new issue
          </a>
        </div>enter code here
```

Any help would be appreciated i'm trying to edit another persons VBA that left.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a combination of css selectors

```
ie.document.querySelector("button[data-csm-counter=createViewTryAgainButton]").click
```

Comment: Though it does look like you copied html during an error so the html may have been altered.